# mocha javascript unit testing a function that return html string

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, tdd, mocha.js, chai

i have a function that return a html string "" from array,

trying to write a mocha test for it. but the white spaces and \n are giving me hard time if i try to assert identical, and its not also flexiable to test html as if its string !.

how do you write tests for pure functions that return html strings ?

example:

```
renderHtml(json){
  // .. function that parse json and return <table> of its content.
}
```

how can i test this function ?

```
  var mod = require('./render');
  var count = (s1,s2) => (s1.match(new RegExp(s2, 'gi'))||[]).length;
  describe('should handle simple array', function () {
    let json = [{ "id": "1", "name": "momen" }];
    let result = mod.renderHtml(json);

    it('should have 1 h1', function () {
      assert.equal(count(result, '<h1>'), 1);
    })

    it('should have 4 ths', function () {
      assert.equal(count(result, '<th>'), 4);
    })

    it('should have 2 tr', function () {
      assert.equal(count(result, '<tr>'), 2);
    })

    it('should have 2 td', function () {
      assert.equal(count(result, '<td>'), 2);
    })
  })
```

i want to test result to be contain  tag, and table with X number of ths and X number or rows that contain X number of tds each row

Answer (score 2):

Suspect you've found solution already, but I had similar problem recently and couldn't find answer. So for the benefit of others.

Problem was exactly the same, how to test typescript class that renders an HTML block from an object/json input. I found the solution to be to use the cheerio plugin (https://cheerio.js.org/) that converts the html string into an html object, and then use can utilise cheerio's jquery syntax to access elements and test contents. I will provide answer by providing working example from solution.

requires: npm install cheerio --save-dev

My rendering class:

```
constructor(private cardOverallStatus: ICardOverallStatus) {
}

@readOnly
public getTemplate() {
    return `
        <section class="goodservice">
            <h1>${this.cardOverallStatus.message}</h1>
        </section>
        ${this.getCardPartsTemplate()}
    `;
}

private getCardPartsTemplate(): string {
    if (!this.cardOverallStatus.modes || this.cardOverallStatus.modes.length === 0) {
        return "";
    }

    let template = `
        <section class="goodservice-list">
            <ul>
        `;
    this.cardOverallStatus.modes.forEach((mode) => {
        template += `<li>${mode}</li>`;
    });
    template += `
            </ul>
        </section>
        `;
    return template;
}
```

My testing class:

```
import { CardOverallStatusTemplate } from './card-overall-status-template';
import { cardTypes } from "./../enums/card-types";
import { expect } from 'chai';
import * as cheerio from 'cheerio';
import 'mocha';

/* Just wanting to test the smallest part of the template - the card OverallStatus */
describe('Card Overall Status Template Unit-Test', () => {

  /* common constants */
  const bodyTag = 'body';
  const sectionTag = 'section';
  const h1Tag = 'h1';
  const liTag = 'li';
  const goodServiceClass = 'goodservice';
  const goodServiceListClass = 'goodservice-list';
  const goodServiceHeader = 'Good service on all lines';
  const tubeMode = 'Tube';
  const tramMode = 'Tram';

  describe('getTemplate() Unit-Test', () => {
    /* these variable must be defined exlcusively within this specific describe pattern, otherwise the final load is used for all tests */
    var template: CardOverallStatusTemplate;
    var result: string;
    var $: CheerioStatic;

    const cardOverallStatus = {
      'type': cardTypes.OVERALL_STATUS,
      'message': 'Good service on all lines',
      'modes': ['Tube', 'Overground', 'TfL Rail', 'DLR', 'Tram']
    };

    template = new CardOverallStatusTemplate(cardOverallStatus);
    result = template.getTemplate();
    $ = cheerio.load(result);

    it('should return two sections', () => {
      expect($(`${bodyTag} > ${sectionTag}`).length).to.equal(2);
    })
    it('should return first section with "goodservice" class', () => {
      expect($(`${bodyTag} > ${sectionTag}`).first().hasClass(goodServiceClass)).to.equal(true);
    })
    it('should return first section header with "Good service on all lines"', () => {
      expect($(`${bodyTag} > ${sectionTag}.${goodServiceClass} ${h1Tag}`).first().html()).to.equal(goodServiceHeader);
    })
    it('should return second section with "goodservice-list" class', () => {
      expect($(`${bodyTag} > ${sectionTag}`).first().next().hasClass(goodServiceListClass)).to.equal(true);
    })
    it(`should return second section with number of li items to match number of modes = ${cardOverallStatus.modes.length}`, () => {
      expect($(`${bodyTag} > ${sectionTag}.${goodServiceListClass} ${liTag}`).length).to.equal(cardOverallStatus.modes.length);
    })
    it('should return second section with first mode of "Tube"', () => {
      expect($(`${bodyTag} > ${sectionTag}.${goodServiceListClass} ${liTag}`).first().html()).to.equal(tubeMode);
    })
    it('should return second section with last mode of "Tram"', () => {
      expect($(`${bodyTag} > ${sectionTag}.${goodServiceListClass} ${liTag}`).last().html()).to.equal(tramMode);
    })
  })
})
```